# Problem with for loop terminating on an error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if (url.match(/^https?:\/\/(www.youtube.com|youtube.com)\/playlist(.*)$/)) {
  const playlist = await youtube.getPlaylist(url);
  const videos = await playlist.getVideos();
  for (const video of Object.values(videos)) {
    try {
      const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id);
    } catch (err) {
      return console.log("Could not get a video!")
    }
    await handleVideo(video2, msg, voiceChannel, true);
  }
  return msg.channel.send(`✅ Playlist: **${playlist.title}** has been added to the queue!`);
}
```

Ok, so the current problem I have is that when the video i request from youtube is private it returns this error --->

```
Error: resource youtube#videoListResponse not found
```

What i'm trying to do, is if the code returns an error in the for loop it does not terminate the loop, and however just returns in the console "Video could not be found".

Any help would be appreciated!

-Thanks, D12.

```js
async function handleVideo(video, msg, voiceChannel, playlist = false) {
  const serverQueue = queue.get(msg.guild.id);
  const song = {
    id: video.id,
    title: Util.escapeMarkdown(video.title),
    url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id}`
  };
  if (!serverQueue) {
    const queueConstruct = {
      textChannel: msg.channel,
      voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
      connection: null,
      songs: [],
      volume: 1,
      playing: true
    };
    queue.set(msg.guild.id, queueConstruct);

    queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

    try {
      var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
      queueConstruct.connection = connection;
      play(msg.guild, queueConstruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
      queue.delete(msg.guild.id);
      return msg.channel.send(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
    }
  } else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    songtitle = song.title;
    if (playlist) return undefined;
    else
      return msg.channel.send({
        embed: {
          color: 3447003,
          author: {
            name: client.user.username,
            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
          },
          title: "Added to music queue!",
          url: "http://google.com",
          description: "✅ Your song has been added to the queue!",
        fields: [{
            name: "Song:",
            value: (song.title + "\n" + song.url)
          },],
          timestamp: new Date(),
          footer: {
            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
            text: "© Nexus music"
          }
        }
      });
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

handleVideo() function ^

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but wouldn't you just not `return` on the catch? (and handleVideo in the try?)

Comment: Does your catch block executing .
Are you printing this message "Video could not be found" or this one "Could not get a video!"

Comment: @saravana it returns "Could not get a video" and then terminates the for loop and doesn't run the last part of the code which prints that the playlist has been added.However, i can easily change what the console logs its just the for loop terminating thats the problem.

Comment: @danh The handleVideo is in a different function and I have updated the code to include the handle function for you.

Comment: try {
      const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id);
    await handleVideo(video2, msg, voiceChannel, true);
    } catch (err) {
      return console.log("Could not get a video!")
    }

Comment: Call  await  handleVideo inside try block then your loop will not terminate,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I might be misunderstanding, but what I'm trying to say in comments is:

```
try {
      const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id);
      await handleVideo(video2, msg, voiceChannel, true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`error is ${err})  // <---- don't return
    }
```